# How to load new scenes or models from network in unity or unreal engine?

Tags: unity, multiplayer, unreal-4, online, character-development

I have a project to be done. I had done some research to accomplish some features. Event so, I couldn't find some answers.

The project needs to have some features as follow;
Charachter creation in runtime to be used as an avatar for a user.
Online/Multiplayer interaction with others.
Network updates for scenes and models.

I looked for unity a bit and I am able to do a dummy gameobject and move it around the scene. These types of things are easy to be done as I see. But what I havn't find out yet is;

How I can allow the user create his/her own model with variaty of hairstyles, cloths etc. and save it in localy. When he/she becomes online, that avatar or model of his/her should be updated to the server and donwloaded by the other clients. Or another approach can be modifying the base character and transfer just required some parameters between clients and server rather than the actual model.

It can be interactive and dynamic, therefore it can be flexible as it can accept to import some models or scenes for some specific events or period of the year. Let's say I want to create a theme with Christmas and add some model accordingly. How should the software/game accept those models and know the parameters.

As far as I see, everything is done in coding section. But, I need to upload those model into server and create new event. then clients should get that event and model/scene updates, without needing to create additional executable with new models.

For now I don't have any idea about the server side though. How to setup such environment and communicate?

I know I coudn't done anything so far to show and ask where the problem is, I just need some starting points.

thanks for reading. Have nice day.

Comment: Dont save and share the model but how it is modified, for example which haircut the character is using, or what scale the nose is.

Comment: Are you talking about DLC, downloadable content? that _you_ create and add to the game as a DLC. Or any user can import and create models?

Comment: I don't know what DLC is for now. I will look for it. But all the models will be done by my side and a notification will be promt to the clients to know, there is a new event, lets say join the event it will download the new models for that event lets assume it is a christmass event, and I will push some christmass tree to the server and when a client enters the event he/she will download the model and enter the event and created new envirenment with christmass theme.

Comment: I just looked for the DLC and I suppose It does what I intendet to do. I guess I need to look for it.

But again, I still don't have information about, how to deform a model at runtime and save parameters for charachter creation. or match the accessoris for all outfits, all haircuts to all head shapes.

Comment: I count many questions here. 1) How to load new model data from a remote service. 2) How to deform a model like a character creator tool. 3) How to represent and save a player's customized character for later re-use. 4) How to notify clients of new character content availability. 5) How to set up & communicate with a server. Each one of these should be a separate question post (and in fact, many already are answered in other questions on this site) Overall, the impression is that you are biting off more than you can chew for a first project, and you may want to start with a simpler tutorial.

Comment: Hi @DMGregory, you are partially ture. I am aware of there are many questions to be asked. But that was not my first intention. I am trying to find a way to do what I want to achive finally. therefore, I am looking for the availability of things. I won't do most of the things, I am just trying to figure out what should be done, and for that purpose who do I need to look for. I am certainly aware of from 3 to 5 questions have the answers in this platform. I just couldn't find the answer of first 2 questions. After knowing DLC I looked for it and I become sure that works for me.